# Disable ONE of the Twitter Bootstrap responsive layouts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to disable one of the Responsive layouts. Whatever the second smallest layout is before it switches to the mobile view.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are compiling from the LESS files, this is quite easy. Open up `responsive.less` and under "`MEDIA QUERIES`" comment out or remove the `@import` declaration for whichever layout you don't want. For example, if you didn't want the Tablets to regular desktops one, the code would look like this:

```
// MEDIA QUERIES
// ------------------

// Phones to portrait tablets and narrow desktops
@import "responsive-767px-max.less";

// Tablets to regular desktops
// @import "responsive-768px-979px.less"; // commented this out because I don't like it

// Large desktops
@import "responsive-1200px-min.less";
```

After that just recompile `bootstrap.less` and you should be done.

If, on the other hand, you're not compiling from `bootstrap.less` and are using `bootstrap-responsive.css` directly, you can search for the media query for the specific device and remove/comment out that section.

For example, removing the portrait tablet one would look like (in `bootstrap-responsive.css`):

```
/* some CSS code above this */

.hidden-desktop {
  display: none !important;
}

/* comment out the following rule entirely in order to disable it */
/*
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .visible-phone {
    display: inherit !important;
  }
  .hidden-phone {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .hidden-desktop {
    display: inherit !important;
  }
  .visible-desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
}*/ /* stop commenting out, we want everything below this */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .visible-tablet {
    display: inherit !important;
  }

/* More CSS code follows */
```

To find out which `@media` query corresponds to which device width, take a look at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive; the media queries are given there along with the device sizes they correspond to.

Comment: This is what I ended up trying. Oddly I tried commenting out each version and none of them shut off the one that I wanted shut off.

Comment: That's odd. Was this in the less file or `bootstrap-responsive`?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - thanks (well almost exactly; I wanted to disable the 1200px-min one too)

Comment: I was also looking to disable the 1200px one. I'm using the [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/) gem with Rails. Since the bootstrap-responsive.scss file is only 7 lines long, I copied it to my app/assets/stylesheets and include my version, which comments out the `@import "bootstrap/responsive-1200px-min"` line. All these solutions mean revisiting each time a new Bootstrap is released.

Comment: See the answer from @TravMcKinney below.  It's preferred because you don't have to modify the bootstrap files themselves.

Answer (score 3):

As an improvement to [spinningarrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342886/spinningarrow)'s way to do this when using LESS is to set the `@gridColumnWidth768` and `@gridGutterWidth768` to match `@gridColumnWidth` and `@gridGutterWidth` like so:

```
@gridColumnWidth768: @gridColumnWidth;
@gridGutterWidth768: @gridGutterWidth;
```

As a rule, I try to leave alone vendor files and only edit them as a last resort. This allows me to fix this issue without having to edit the core bootstrap files.

Answer (score 0):

- call your css after the bootstrap call.
- In your css copy the row, span css form the layout you want and place it in your css.
- change the media query to something like this (The max width is the width you like to stick to):

```css
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .row {
        margin-left: -30px;
        *zoom: 1;
    }
    .row:before,
    .row:after {
        display: table;
        content: "";
        line-height: 0;
    }
    .row:after {
        clear: both;
    }
    [class*="span"] {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    .container,
    .navbar-static-top .container,
    .navbar-fixed-top .container,
    .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
        width: 1170px;
    }
    .span12 {
        width: 1170px;
    }
    .span11 {
        width: 1070px;
    }
    .span10 {
        width: 970px;
    }
    .span9 {
        width: 870px;
    }
    .span8 {
        width: 770px;
    }
    .span7 {
        width: 670px;
    }
    .span6 {
        width: 570px;
    }
    .span5 {
        width: 470px;
    }
    .span4 {
        width: 370px;
    }
    .span3 {
        width: 270px;
    }
    .span2 {
        width: 170px;
    }
    .span1 {
        width: 70px;
    }
    .offset12 {
        margin-left: 1230px;
    }
    .offset11 {
        margin-left: 1130px;
    }
    .offset10 {
        margin-left: 1030px;
    }
    .offset9 {
        margin-left: 930px;
    }
    .offset8 {
        margin-left: 830px;
    }
    .offset7 {
        margin-left: 730px;
    }
    .offset6 {
        margin-left: 630px;
    }
    .offset5 {
        margin-left: 530px;
    }
    .offset4 {
        margin-left: 430px;
    }
    .offset3 {
        margin-left: 330px;
    }
    .offset2 {
        margin-left: 230px;
    }
    .offset1 {
        margin-left: 130px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you aren't compiling LESS, the best way I've found is going into bootstrap.css and commenting out the size you don't want active. The CSS is pretty well-organized, and disabling one of the sizes doesn't appear to affect anything else.

(Of course, you have to be careful you don't re-enable them when updating Bootstrap.)