# How To Disable The .XS Bootstrap Layout In Custom CSS File

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been given the task of customising certain elements of a site which is using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.2.

The site will be using default Bootstrap styles and responsive layouts except for a particular custom CSS theme file whose modified styles will only be applied when certain users access the site via certain means.

In any event, I need to disable just the .xs responsive layout and nothing else. This means that the screen must retain a small screen layout on resolutions below 767px.

I've looked at many answers on this site and the closest one is this one that describes [editing the existing bootstrap.css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726271/disable-one-of-the-twitter-bootstrap-responsive-layouts).

I don't want to edit the core bootstrap files but simply want to override the .xs layout in a custom CSS file that is called after the bootstrap file.

I'm not sure how or what I should be editing as the media queries look like the following and it's a bit confusing to me.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs,
  tr.hidden-xs,
  th.hidden-xs,
  td.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-sm.hidden-xs,
  tr.hidden-sm.hidden-xs,
  th.hidden-sm.hidden-xs,
  td.hidden-sm.hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Any and all answers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.