# Disable ONE of the Twitter Bootstrap responsive layouts in Bootstrap 3.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Something of a reposting of [Disable ONE of the Twitter Bootstrap responsive layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726271/disable-one-of-the-twitter-bootstrap-responsive-layouts), but focused on the newly-released Bootstrap 3.2.  I'd like to drop the "middle" (768px) layout, such that anything at 768 or below goes into the "collapsed" view.  Not surprisingly, the files in the new Bootstrap release have changed relative to 2.x, such that the old instructions no longer pertain.  Any advice out there?  Thanks!

[meta-issue: My guess was that it was better to post this question as a new issue rather than having the discussion of it buried in comments in the cited "Disable ONE..." post.  If that's wrong, we can adjust...]

Comment: I'm just curious...why do you want to "disable" the layout?  If you want everything to collapse below 991px, just use only the col-lg-* and col-md-* classes.  Is the concern that you want to have a light(er)weight css file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the grid works, there's no customization needed to make "anything at 768 or below [go] into the "collapsed" view."

In Bootstrap 3, the focus is mobile first, so everything by default is 100% the width of the container UP TO the point that you tell it to be different.  (Perhaps this was what GuNs was trying to say).

So, if you want everything below 768px to be "collapsed", you don't need to use the xs classes.  If you wanted everything below 992px to be collapsed, don't use the sm classes.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>This content will be in 2 columns above 767px.</p> 
    </div> <!-- /col-sm-6 -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>Below that it will be the full width of the container.</p>
    </div> <!-- /col-sm-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>This content will be in 2 columns above 991px.</p> 
    </div> <!-- /col-md-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Below 992px this will be the full width of the container.</p>
    </div> <!-- /col-md-6 -->
  </div> <!-- /row -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: This is helpful; thanks.  All of this came up in the process of moving a site from Bootstrap 2.3 to 3.2, and I clearly need to learn more about the xs/sm/md/lg stuff.  I moved all my old site's .span classes into .col-md-*, which is generally working quite well, but it looks like getting the other details in place may require a little more, um, finesse (that is, learn how the new stuff actually works).

Comment: I get it. I felt the same way when moving from 2 to 3, but it's worth the effort.  I really think 3 is a lot easier and more intuitive once you get your head around some of its core concepts.  Much luck to you.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to adjust the values of [the `@screen-*` Less variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/8ad583063bd11e1b8841e1f27207660e0181df19/less/variables.less#L261) accordingly. They define the boundaries of the various abstract screen sizes (XS, SM, MD, LG).
[The Bootstrap customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) also lets you modify these variables.