# Prevent navbar breaking at 768px

Tags: css, navbar

I am building a navbar that uses jasny-bootstrap off canvas menu and bootstrap default. The issue I am having is, I don't want the navbar to start collapsing at 768px. I know you can change this in the CSS but I have no idea how to, even searching all over the web and trying the suggestions.

I want the search to remain hidden inside the navbar for tablets and only shown when it is on larger desktops. In the html, I am displaying jasny-bootstrap off canvas menu when on small screens and hidden when on large and vice versa with bootstrap default navbar. I want to be able to this just by CSS alone.

New coder here. Any help appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Navigation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar hidden-xs hidden-sm">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Practices <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Project Delievery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Architecture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Business Analysis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Development & Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enterprise Testing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Infustructure & Operations</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>  
      </nav>
    </div>

    <!-- off canvas toggle -->
    <div id="off-canvas-nav" class="off-canvas-nav hidden-md hidden-lg">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#myNavmenu" data-canvas="body">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      </div><!-- /pull-left -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#search-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i>
      </button>        
      </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /off-canvas -->

    <!-- search -->
    <div id="search-tool">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="search-navbar-collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
              <a class="btn btn-default" a href="#" role="button">Search</a>
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-lg"></i></a></button>
          </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div><!-- /form-group -->
      </form>
    </div><!-- collapse -->
    </div>

    <!-- off canvas menu-->
    <div id="off-canvas-menu">
    <nav id="myNavmenu" class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Practices<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu navmenu-nav" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Project Delivery</a>
            <li><a href="#">Architecture</a>
            <li><a href="#">Business Analysis</a>
            <li><a href="#">Development & Support</a>
            <li><a href="#">Enterprise Testing</a>
            <li><a href="#">Infustructure & Operations</a>
          </ul><!-- /dropdown-menu -->
        <li><a href="#">Document Library</a>
        <li><a href="#">Lists</a>
      </ul><!-- /nav -->
    </nav>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: initial;
    }
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #006564;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-default, .navbar-toggle {
    border: 0px;
}
.navbar-default > .pull-left .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.navmenu-default {
    background-color: #006564;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #006564;
}
.navmenu, .navbar-offcanvas {
    padding-top: 54px;
}
.navmenu-default .navmenu-nav > li > a, .navbar-default .navbar-offcanvas .navmenu-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
}
.navmenu-default .navmenu-nav .dropdown-menu, .navbar-default .navbar-offcanvas .navmenu-nav .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #367d79;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.form-control {
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.fa {
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-form > .form-group, .input-group, .btn-default {
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #367d79;
    border-color: #367d79;
}
.input-group-btn:last-child > .btn, .input-group-btn:last-child > .btn-group {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@media` rule in your CSS ? I don't use your specific framework but [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries) are made to change CSS properties based on size or other parameters and this one change the display property when the screen is wider than 768px.

Comment: Maybe look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726271/disable-one-of-the-twitter-bootstrap-responsive-layouts